# UITextView contain Bold and Regular string

Tags: string, swift, nsstring, uitextview

I would like to add a string to my `UITextView` and I would like some to be in bold and some in regular font. How should It do this? I have an example of what I would like to achieve below.

Thanks

```
myTextView.text = "This is my string. "
```

This **is** my **string**.

Below is the attempts I have made.

```
    // Define string attributes
    let font = UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 18.0) ?? UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18.0)
    let textFont = [NSFontAttributeName:font]

    let fontItal = UIFont(name: "Georgia-Italic", size: 40.0) ?? UIFont.systemFontOfSize(40.0)
    let italFont = [NSFontAttributeName:fontItal]

    // Create a string that will be our paragraph
    let para = NSMutableAttributedString()

    // Create locally formatted strings
    let attrString1 = NSAttributedString(string: "This is ", attributes:textFont)
    let attrString2 = NSAttributedString(string: "my", attributes:italFont)
    let attrString3 = NSAttributedString(string: " string.", attributes:textFont)

    // Add locally formatted strings to paragraph
    para.appendAttributedString(attrString1)
    para.appendAttributedString(attrString2)
    para.appendAttributedString(attrString3)

    // Define paragraph styling
    let paraStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paraStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 15.0
    paraStyle.paragraphSpacingBefore = 10.0

    // Apply paragraph styles to paragraph
    para.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: paraStyle, range: NSRange(location: 0,length: para.length))


    // Add string to UITextView

    myTextView.attributedText = para
```

Comment: Please show the attempts that you've already made at solving the problem.

Comment: Alright, and how do the results you're receiving differ from what you expect?

Comment: The text does not change. It displays the string in the default font (helvetica) with no italics.

Answer (score 10):

See this code

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
```

...

```
var text: NSString = "This is my string"
var attributedText: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)

attributedText.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(14)], range: NSRange(location: 5, length: 2))
attributedText.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(14)], range: NSRange(location: 11, length: 6))

textField.attributedText = attributedText
textView.attributedText = attributedText
```

This is the output:
[image]

Comment: It is still displaying it all in regular text instead of some bold. Is this because I am using a `UITextView` ?

Comment: I've tried it with UITextView as well and it works. As you can see in the updated answer

Comment: My 'UITextView' is created programatically. Will this make any difference?

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference, I've just ran your code and it works.
http://imgur.com/3COlzUe

Comment: Great! Thanks :-) Guys, remember to Enable Attributed Text in the TextField